# How can I redirect 404 to home in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I want to redirect this url `http://www.businessbid.ae/stagging/web/feedback`
to `http://www.businessbid.ae`. What can I do?

Comment: I would advise against doing this, it's better to display a meaningful error message and send a HTTP 404 than it is to just redirect to the homepage, which can potentially be quite confusing for a user who is either expecting content or a message explaining why they can't get at the content

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should create a listener to listen for the `onKernelExceptionEvent`.
In that you can check for the 404 status code and set the redirect response from that.

<kbd>AppBundle\EventListener\Redirect404ToHomepageListener</kbd>

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;

class Redirect404ToHomepageListener
{
    /**
     * @var RouterInterface
     */
    private $router;

    /**
     * @var RouterInterface $router
     */
    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /**
     * @var GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event
     * @return null
     */
    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        // If not a HttpNotFoundException ignore
        if (!$event->getException() instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
            return;
        }

        // Create redirect response with url for the home page
        $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('home_page'));

        // Set the response to be processed
        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

<kbd>services.yml</kbd>

```
services:
    app.listener.redirect_404_to_homepage:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\Redirect404ToHomepageListener
        arguments:
            - "@router"
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException }
```

Comment: is it run by default whenever it found 404?

Comment: The exception listener is called every time there is an exception. The `NotFoundHttpException` is generated when there is no route to match the request path. In short, yes.

Comment: Are you getting anything in the logs? Have you cleared your cache? Is the event listener being loaded (does it show up in `app/console debug:event-dispatcher kernel.exception`)?

Comment: And did that help or are we leaving it at that?

Comment: Shockingly, neither is "no ! i havent clear cache".  Have you tried to clear the cache since? What about the other things in my previous question?

Comment: You need a
    `use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to override default [Exception Controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html#overriding-the-default-exceptioncontroller). IMHO better solution is to do that job in `.htaccess` or nginx config.

Comment: can you please share any example?

Comment: check out this apache documentation [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/custom-error.html#page-header)   in the configuration section

Answer (score 0):

Try this into your controller:

```
$this->redirect($this->generateUrl('route_name')));
```

Comment: every time when controller finds no response ..it automatically redirect to home! Does it possible? and there are more than 10 controllers??

Comment: this is second question Varun

Comment: try this 'public function indexAction(Request $request) {  // check $request object and redirect}'

Comment: This approach would only work when you have a response, which would defeat the purpose of having it.